# TFS Properties of an Activity Workflow, how can I put a path to the VB Expression

Tags: android-activity, tfs, workflow

I'm following this tuto: http://blog.justtfs.co.uk/2014/09/movedeployfiles-copy-file-activity-for.html

But how can I put the path in the VB expression:

[image]

For example if I put in the argument RepositoryPath: C:\agent, it doesn't work
So, how is the syntax?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is a [VB expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1w3te48(VS.100).aspx).
Some Examples.

- A constant string: `"C:\agent"`
- Value of `SourcesDirectory` variable: `SourcesDirectory`
- Compose variable with string `SourcesDirectory + "\subdir"`

As per the accepted values, they depend on the specific activity's property.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but I don't understand yet. If I want to have as value for DestinationDirectory, which expression can I use? For instance I want to a specific path like C:\DestinationDirectory

Comment: @FrankVDB Like Giulio said above, you just enter "C:\Destination\...". Enter a specify path with double quotes to make it as a string.

Comment: So I have to put for instance "C:\DestinationDirectory". I ask because I have other errors, but it seems that this one is fixed.